# Youtube API Upload noauth_local_webserver

Tags: api, youtube

I am trying to upload a video using Youtube API.
When I run the scripts, I recieve below message.I am not too sure how to fix this issues. Please help.

> Your browser has been opened to visit:
>
> ```
> https://accounts.xxxxxx
> ```
>
> If your browser is on a different machine then exit and re-run this
> application with the command-line parameter
>
> --noauth_local_webserver

My script is from below is from following links with only few changes.
[Youtube API overview link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video)

below is my actual script.

```
import http.client
import httplib2
import os
import random
import sys
import time
 
from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import argparser, run_flow
 
 
# Explicitly tell the underlying HTTP transport library not to retry, since
# we are handling retry logic ourselves.
httplib2.RETRIES = 1
 
# Maximum number of times to retry before giving up.
MAX_RETRIES = 10
 
# Always retry when these exceptions are raised.
RETRIABLE_EXCEPTIONS = (httplib2.HttpLib2Error, IOError, http.client.NotConnected,
  http.client.IncompleteRead, http.client.ImproperConnectionState,
  http.client.CannotSendRequest, http.client.CannotSendHeader,
  http.client.ResponseNotReady, http.client.BadStatusLine)
 
# Always retry when an apiclient.errors.HttpError with one of these status
# codes is raised.
RETRIABLE_STATUS_CODES = [500, 502, 503, 504]
 
# The CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE variable specifies the name of a file that contains
# the OAuth 2.0 information for this application, including its client_id and
# client_secret. You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from
# the Google API Console at
# https://console.developers.google.com/.
# Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
# For more information about using OAuth2 to access the YouTube Data API, see:
#   https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication
# For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, see:
#   https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "G:/Python Scripts/client_secrets.json"
 
# This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
# authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
YOUTUBE_UPLOAD_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"
 
# This variable defines a message to display if the CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE is
# missing.
MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE = """
WARNING: Please configure OAuth 2.0
 
To make this sample run you will need to populate the client_secrets.json file
found at:
 
   %s
 
with information from the API Console
https://console.developers.google.com/
 
For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, please visit:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
""" % os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname('__file__'),
                                   CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE))
 
VALID_PRIVACY_STATUSES = ("public", "private", "unlisted")
 
 
def get_authenticated_service(args):
  flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE,
    scope=YOUTUBE_UPLOAD_SCOPE,
    message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE)
 
  storage = Storage("%s-oauth2.json" % sys.argv[0])
  credentials = storage.get()
 
  if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = run_flow(flow, storage, args)
 
  return build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
    http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))
 
def initialize_upload(youtube, options):
  tags = None
  if options.keywords:
    tags = options.keywords.split(",")
 
  body=dict(
    snippet=dict(
      title=options.title,
      description=options.description,
      tags=tags,
      categoryId=options.category
    ),
    status=dict(
      privacyStatus=options.privacyStatus
    )
  )
 
  # Call the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
  insert_request = youtube.videos().insert(
    part=",".join(body.keys()),
    body=body,
    # The chunksize parameter specifies the size of each chunk of data, in
    # bytes, that will be uploaded at a time. Set a higher value for
    # reliable connections as fewer chunks lead to faster uploads. Set a lower
    # value for better recovery on less reliable connections.
    #
    # Setting "chunksize" equal to -1 in the code below means that the entire
    # file will be uploaded in a single HTTP request. (If the upload fails,
    # it will still be retried where it left off.) This is usually a best
    # practice, but if you're using Python older than 2.6 or if you're
    # running on App Engine, you should set the chunksize to something like
    # 1024 * 1024 (1 megabyte).
    media_body=MediaFileUpload(options.file, chunksize=-1, resumable=True)
  )
 
  resumable_upload(insert_request)
 
# This method implements an exponential backoff strategy to resume a
# failed upload.
def resumable_upload(insert_request):
  response = None
  error = None
  retry = 0
  while response is None:
    try:
      print("Uploading file...")
      status, response = insert_request.next_chunk()
      if response is not None:
        if 'id' in response:
          print("Video id '%s' was successfully uploaded." % response['id'])
        else:
          exit("The upload failed with an unexpected response: %s" % response)
    except HttpError as e:
      if e.resp.status in RETRIABLE_STATUS_CODES:
        error = "A retriable HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status,
                                                             e.content)
      else:
        raise
    except RETRIABLE_EXCEPTIONS as e:
      error = "A retriable error occurred: %s" % e
 
    if error is not None:
      print(error)
      retry += 1
      if retry > MAX_RETRIES:
        exit("No longer attempting to retry.")
 
      max_sleep = 2 ** retry
      sleep_seconds = random.random() * max_sleep
      print("Sleeping %f seconds and then retrying..." % sleep_seconds)
      time.sleep(sleep_seconds)
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
  argparser.add_argument("--file", required=True, help="2.mp4")
  argparser.add_argument("--title", help="Video title", default="Test Title")
  argparser.add_argument("--description", help="Video description",
    default="Test Description")
  argparser.add_argument("--category", default="27",
    help="Numeric video category. " +
      "See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list")
  argparser.add_argument("--keywords", help="Video keywords, comma separated",
    default="")
  argparser.add_argument("--privacyStatus", choices=VALID_PRIVACY_STATUSES,
    default=VALID_PRIVACY_STATUSES[0], help="Video privacy status.")
  args = argparser.parse_args(["--file", "2.MP4","--title","Test Title","--description","Video description","--category","27","--keywords","kids education","--privacyStatus",VALID_PRIVACY_STATUSES[0]])
 #you can populate other optional parameters, not just positionals/required
#args = argparser.parse_args(["--file", "myfile.avi", "--title", "my title"])
  if not os.path.exists(args.file):
    exit("Please specify a valid file using the --file= parameter.")
 
  youtube = get_authenticated_service(args)
  try:
    initialize_upload(youtube, args)
  except HttpError as e:
    print("An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status, e.content))
```

Comment: _"When I run the scripts"_ - what scripts? Did you really think we could help you find problems in code that you have not shown us in the first place ...? Please go read [ask] and [mre], and the edit your question accordingly.

Comment: you are right. my sincerely apologies. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video